# python - finding cosine similarity between two groups of vectors in the most efficient way

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, cosine-similarity

I am trying to calculate the average cosine similarity between two groups of sentences. After converting the sentences to embeddings, I need to calculate avg. similarities in the most efficient way. Here, what I have tried and the time is taken. Is there any way to improve this calculation?

I also put the slower approaches to help you to understand the case.

X_num is the pandas.Series of embedding vectors, each row is generally 512, 768, 1024 or 2048 long.

class1_indexes : all the indexes of the instances that belong to class 1.
class2_indexes : all the indexes of the instances that belong to class 2.

I need to calculate cosine similarities between each vector pair from class 1 and class 2. Totally, my output should be a cosine similarity vector of len(class1_indexes)*len(class2_indexes ) long.
I edited the code as it includes the test case and you can see that run times for the approaches are like:

t1 > t2 > t3

The third approach is faster 20x times. But I'm looking for much faster approaches.

Thanks in advance.

```
sample_in_each_class = 1000
X_num = pd.Series([np.random.random(10) for i in range(2*sample_in_each_class)])
class1_indexes = list(range(sample_in_each_class))
class2_indexes = list(range(sample_in_each_class,2*sample_in_each_class))
```

approach 1

```
def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
    norm1 = np.linalg.norm(vec1)
    norm2 = np.linalg.norm(vec2)
    if norm1 == 0:
        norm1 += 0.00001
    if norm2 == 0:
        norm2 += 0.00001  
    return np.dot(vec1, vec2)/(norm1*norm2)
    
approach1 = []
for idx1 in class1_indexes:
    for idx2 in class2_indexes:
        approach1.append(cosine_similarity(X_num.loc[idx1], X_num.loc[idx2]))
```

approach 2

```
import itertools
vectors_product = itertools.product(X_num[class1_indexes], X_num[class2_indexes])
vectors_product = pd.Series(list(vectors_product))
approach2 = vectors_product.apply(lambda x: cosine_similarity(x[0], x[1]))
```

approach 3

```
vectors_product = itertools.product(X_num[class1_indexes], X_num[class2_indexes])
vectors_product = np.array(list(vectors_product))
first_part = vectors_product[:,0,:]
second_part = vectors_product[:,1,:]

numerator = np.sum(np.multiply(first_part, second_part), axis=1)
denominator = (np.multiply(np.linalg.norm(first_part, axis=1), 
                           np.linalg.norm(second_part, axis=1)))
approach3 = numerator / denominator
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input/output (possibly random)? It would be great so to check results and compare the performance with your functions.

Comment: edited the code to add a test case, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify the sentence "each row is generally 512, 768, 1024 or 2048 long" since the example have only 10 items. Are the number of items variable per row? If so, storing the information in a big array makes much more sense than a dataframe of many Numpy arrays (at least performance-wise). It looks like they are from your code.

Comment: The length of the vectors depends on the embedding method, you can think that all of them have the same length. Since I am trying different embeddings, length changes and some of them are too long. This is why I am looking for an efficient method. When I need to calculate something I change them to an array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way is:

1. Convert your data to two numpy ndarrays, an array for each group. I assume rows are embedding vectors and arrays are called X1 and X2.
2. Do `X/np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1)` on each array.
3. Then do `np.dot(X1, X2.T)`
4. Then flatten the resulting matrix if you want.

Comment: @JérômeRichard well then he also can't calculate a cosine distance on vectors of different sizes. He should group vectors that have the same size in numpy arrays and use the above method.

Comment: You can think that all the vectors have the same length in each scenario. It differs when the embedding method is changed.